# Why won't Canon EOS 400D turn on?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, power, canon-400d

I have the Canon EOS 400D - also known as EOS Digital Rebel XTi, or Kiss Digital X in Japan - and as of tonight, it stopped working. It won't do anything, with or without batteries or a CF card, except flash a blue light in the top left when batteries are inside.

I've tried taking both batteries out, the CF card out, letting the capacitors drain (someone suggested) but it still won't work. I know the power works because that blue light keeps flashing. It won't be read by the computer through a direct connection, and I don't have a CF card reader.

I looked inside and it seems like a pin is missing. CF card seems to bear the scars too. I've never looked too closely at the CF card before, so I don't know if the pin was missing before. I have a feeling that's the cause, though.

What can I do?

---

**Edit:**

Missing pin, not bent, but missing. Could this cause the lack of function and the blue flashing light?

[image: image1]

I'm no expert, but this looks damaged.

[image: image2]

Comment: could you give us some pictures of the damages? is the batterie fully loaded for sure?

Comment: Images added. The battery is definitely loaded - I tried both, which are both fully charged.

Comment: Did you try and remove the lens and try to start it?

Comment: I had the same issue with a Canon Rebel T2i and other cameras before; I used a pencil eraser to clean the contacts of the battery terminals inside the camera to remove corrosion. Be careful not to push too hard or else you will get eraser shavings inside.

Comment: The far right pin on the lower row is not missing, but it is bent and thus not reflecting light at the same angle as the other pins. Does the camera turn on with no card installed?

Comment: Andreas, yes, I did try that. I actually thought that was the original cause since I had changed lenses right before.

Comment: Michael C, no, the camera doesn't turn on with or without the card. The only hint of functioning is the print light flashing blue every second, for a fraction of a second, and this only works when the main battery is inserted. I left both batteries and the card out overnight, and nothing changed.

Comment: Alexy13 - didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Did anything happen to the camera recently? Did you drop it? Did you try to flash a new firmware? Did it go for an extended time without use? Did you recently connect the camera to a computer with a USB cable? Have you tried turning the camera on without the CF card? Have you tried reformatting the CF card? How long have you let the camera sit with the blue light flashing before trying to restart it?

Comment: xiota - I connected it to my computer with a USB cable. That's actually the only way I transfer photos - I don't have a CF card reader. Without the camera turning on I can't reformat either CF card. I've left the camera to sit for a long time. I left it with the battery in, power on, overnight, and in the morning the blue light wasn't flashing. But when I put in a new, charged battery, the light flashing resumed. I've tried turning on the camera without the CF card, no luck. I didn't drop it or even severely bump it, and I've been using it frequently - at least once every other day.

Comment: @caiv if that pin is really missing or if it is bent and you do not want to/cannot fix it yourself: you will have to get your camera serviced anyway. Fixing the non-operational/blue LED problem yourself might not make too much sense then, as you'd be left with an operational camera without a working CF-card slot.

Answer (score 1):

The blue light usually indicates file transfer so it may think that it is connected to a computer and trying to transfer files. Try plugging in a USB cable when it is on then pulling it out and see if that gets it out of the loop.

Also try cleaning all the ports and checking if the coin shaped battery needs replacing.